# htaccess rules for angular admin and separate api areas?

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having problems getting my .htaccess file to route requests correctly for my Laravel and Angular app.

```
api
    # Laravel api here
    public/
        ...
public_html/
    .htaccess
    admin/
        index.html
    front/
        index.html
```

I need some help getting setup with a proper .htaccess to route based on the three domain calls I am making:

```
api.domain.com > routes to /api/public
admin.domain.com > routes to /admin/index.html
domain.com > routes to /front/index.html
```

Can anyone help me with this please? one thing is that the original routes should stay the same, `admin.domain.com` should remain the same even though it gets the sub `admin/` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think .htaccess is the correct way to go here, unless you are on a shared hosting that doesn't allow you to create vhosts.

Here is an example vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/front/
    ServerName domain.com

    FallbackResource /index.html

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/admin/
    ServerName admin.domain.com

    FallbackResource /index.html

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/api/public/
    ServerName api.domain.com

    FallbackResource /index.php

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will send all urls except what is a file and is excluded on top. Please test.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

#If static don't change anything and go direct
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteRule \.(ttf|svg|otf|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|ico|swf|css|js|html|htm|woff)((\?.*)|)$ - [L,NC]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} admin.domain.com
RewriteRule .* /admin/index.html [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.com
RewriteRule .* /front/index.html [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} api.domain.com
RewriteRule .* /api/public/index.php [QSA,L,NC]
```